# Lifetime of a temporary object bound to a reference member in member initializer list (C++14)

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, temporary-objects

I'm looking up [lifetime of a temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) on cppreference.com and I found something changed from C++14:

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary or to a base subobject of
>   a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the
>   lifetime of the reference, with the following exceptions:
>
> ...
>
> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as
>   long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as
>   of DR 1696) (until C++14)

I checked the standard there's really no such statement. ($12.2/5 Temporary objects [class.temporary])

Does it mean from C++14 the lifetime of a temporary bound to a reference member will be extended to the object's lifetime?

I've tried the following code with [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2880858cc120f7d1) and [CLANG](http://rextester.com/ZTHX27435) both seem not, the temporary will be destroyed when constructor ends.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    ~X() { std::cout << "X dtor\n"; }
};
struct Y {
    Y() : x_(X()) { std::cout << "Y ctor\n"; }
    const X& x_;
    ~Y() { std::cout << "Y dtor\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    Y y;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

result:

```
Y ctor
X dtor
Hello, world!
Y dtor
```

Do I misunderstand it?

Comment: Did you read the [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1696)?

Comment: **YES** (you did misunderstand it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The defect report you cited has been adopted, and N4582 already includes the new wording in [[class.base.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#8):

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member in a *mem-initializer* is ill-formed. *[Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A() : v(42) { }  // error
>   const int& v;
> };
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

So it's not extended for the object's lifetime - the code is simply ill-formed. gcc and clang both emit warnings on your code on every version I've tried, which I think is conforming but ideally they should error there.

Comment: Merely emitting a warning is non-conforming; unless otherwise stated, if something is `ill-formed", then the compiler must emit a diagonstic. But C++17 isn't finished yet either.

Comment: @NicolBolas A warning is a diagnostic.  As long as an error or warning is served up then it is conforming.

Comment: @NathanOliver the implementation defines whether a warning is a diagnostic or not. Do you have links to the documentation of clang and gcc respectively that support what you said?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule then it *shall issue at least one diagnostic message.*.  A diagnostic message is defined as *message belonging to an implementation-defined subset of the implementation’s output messages* so IMHO if the compiler issues a warning  the compiler satisfies the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver backing up the statement that gcc and clang have defined warning output to be diagnostics by a standard quote does not seem to be sound.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb If you really want links then here you go: [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#enabling-all-diagnostics)(-Weverything enables are warnings so all warnings are diagnostics).

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, that is what I was looking for.